# python loop through list in dictionary inside one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one dictionary containing a list of dictionaries as below:

```
output = { "Facebook": [
    { "prefix": "5.45.32.0\/22", "exact": true },
    { "prefix": "185.160.58.0\/23", "exact": false, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "5.57.248.0\/21", "exact": true },
    { "prefix": "5.206.208.0\/20", "exact": true },
    { "prefix": "185.54.94.0\/23", "exact": false, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "31.193.104.0\/21", "exact": true },
    { "prefix": "213.233.192.0\/18", "exact": true },
    { "prefix": "217.26.96.0\/20", "exact": true }
] }

for line in output:
    print(line['prefix")
```

I want to loop through this en print each line like this:

```
5.45.32.0, True
185.160.58.0, 24
```

So remove `\/22` from the first item for example
Can someone help me understand how can I make it work?

Comment: What about the next items in the list with `/21`,`/20`,... etc? And why `true` in first case but `24` in second case?

Comment: output is not clear. what result are you expecting to get exactly? in terms of Python data types.

Comment: The first item "prefix": "5.45.32.0\/22"  I need 5.45.32.0 and the rest accessing by the key

Comment: `rest accessing by the key`, which key are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = { "Facebook": [
    { "prefix": "5.45.32.0\/22", "exact": 'true' },
    { "prefix": "185.160.58.0\/23", "exact": 'false', "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "5.57.248.0\/21", "exact": 'true' },
    { "prefix": "5.206.208.0\/20", "exact": 'true' },
    { "prefix": "185.54.94.0\/23", "exact": 'false', "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "31.193.104.0\/21", "exact": 'true' },
    { "prefix": "213.233.192.0\/18", "exact": 'true' },
    { "prefix": "217.26.96.0\/20", "exact": 'true'}
] }

for item in output['Facebook']:
    if item['exact'] == 'true':
        print ("{}, {}".format(item['prefix'].split('\/')[0], item['exact']))
    else:
        print ("{}, {}".format(item['prefix'].split('\/')[0], item['greater-equal']))
```

output:

```
5.45.32.0, true
185.160.58.0, 24
5.57.248.0, true
5.206.208.0, true
185.54.94.0, 24
31.193.104.0, true
213.233.192.0, true
217.26.96.0, true
```

or:

> NOTE :difference is if you will use **'true'** like a string or True
>   **like** boolean

```
output = { "Facebook": [
    { "prefix": "5.45.32.0\/22", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "185.160.58.0\/23", "exact": False, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "5.57.248.0\/21", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "5.206.208.0\/20", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "185.54.94.0\/23", "exact": False, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "31.193.104.0\/21", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "213.233.192.0\/18", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "217.26.96.0\/20", "exact": True }
] }


for item in output['Facebook']:
    if item['exact'] == True:
        print ("{}, {}".format(item['prefix'].split('\/')[0], item['exact']))
    else:
        print ("{}, {}".format(item['prefix'].split('\/')[0], item['greater-equal']))
```

Comment: I get this error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
output = { "Facebook": [
    { "prefix": "5.45.32.0\/22", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "185.160.58.0\/23", "exact": False, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "5.57.248.0\/21", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "5.206.208.0\/20", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "185.54.94.0\/23", "exact": False, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "31.193.104.0\/21", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "213.233.192.0\/18", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "217.26.96.0\/20", "exact": True }
] }

#Iterate through all dictionaries
for dct in output['Facebook']:

    #Get value of prefix and exact
    prefix = dct['prefix'].split('\/')[0]
    exact = dct['exact']

    #If exact is present, use it, 
    if exact:
        print('{} {}'.format(prefix, exact))
    #Else use greater-equal key
    else:
        gr_eq = dct.get('greater-equal')
        print('{} {}'.format(prefix, gr_eq))
```

The output will be

```
5.45.32.0 True
185.160.58.0 24
5.57.248.0 True
5.206.208.0 True
185.54.94.0 24
31.193.104.0 True
213.233.192.0 True
217.26.96.0 True
```

Also note that `"exact": true` will throw a syntax error, instead do `"exact": True` since boolean is represented by `True` and not `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
output = { "Facebook": [
    { "prefix": "5.45.32.0\/22", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "185.160.58.0\/23", "exact": False, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "5.57.248.0\/21", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "5.206.208.0\/20", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "185.54.94.0\/23", "exact": False, "greater-equal": 24, "less-equal": 24 },
    { "prefix": "31.193.104.0\/21", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "213.233.192.0\/18", "exact": True },
    { "prefix": "217.26.96.0\/20", "exact": True }
] }

facebook_apis = output['Facebook']

for facebook_api in facebook_apis:
    # print(facebook_api['prefix'])
    try:
        print(str(facebook_api['prefix'].split("\/")[0]) + ', ' + str(facebook_api['greater-equal']))
    except:
        print(str(facebook_api['prefix'].split("\/")[0]) + ", " + str(facebook_api["exact"]))
```

The output will be:

```
5.45.32.0, True
185.160.58.0, 24
5.57.248.0, True
5.206.208.0, True
185.54.94.0, 24
31.193.104.0, True
213.233.192.0, True
217.26.96.0, True
```

Comment: ps, error in your code at **"exact": true** , it can either be **"exact": 'true'** or **"exact": True** and the like.